Question about the action function of the electromagnetic field (Landau & Lifshitz)
In Landau's Classical Field Theory, the action function of the electromagnetic field is constructed based on the following facts (Chapter 4,$\S 27$):

$S_f$ is the integration of sum scalar function over the whole space time $\implies S_f = \iint (\text{Lorentz scalar}) \mathrm{d}V \mathrm{d}t$
EM field satisfies superposition principle $\implies$ the integrand must be quadratic in fields.
potentials cannot enter into the expression of $S_f$ since they are not uniquely determined.
derivative of $F_{\mu\nu}$ cannot enter into the expression of $S_f$ since it can only contains coordinates $A_\mu$ and its first time derivative.

based on (3) and (4), we have $$S_f = a \iint F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} \mathrm{d}V\mathrm{d}t = 2a \iint (\mathbf{B}^2 - \mathbf{E}^2) \mathrm{d}V\mathrm{d}t.$$

since $\mathbf{E}^2$ contains the term $(\partial \mathbf{A} / \partial t)^2$, it must appear in the action with a plus sign since if it follows a minus sign, we can let it change rapidly to make $S_f$ a negative quantity with arbitrary large absolute value. $\implies$ $a$ is negative, and in Gaussian system, $a = -\frac{1}{16\pi}$


Here are my questions:

Question about (3): Even though $A_\mu$ is not uniquely determined, it enters into the expression of $S_{mf} = -\frac{q}{c} \int A_\mu \mathrm{d}x^\mu$. Under a gauge transformation, $S_{mf}$ will pick up a term which depends only on the boundary condition. So why can't $S_f$ behave like this?(i.e. the Lagrangian of EM field is not gauge invariant itself but when integrated, the action $S_f$ is gauge invariant)
Question about (4): Is this just a empirical fact or there are some deeper reasons?
Question about (5): I think this is most confusing. I can apply Landau's argument in another way: Since $\mathbf{B}^2$ contains the term $(\nabla \times \mathbf{A})^2$, if it follows a minus sign, we can let $\mathbf{A}$ be "arbitrarily curly" to make $S_f$ a negative quantity with arbitrary large absolute value. So it seems that $a$ must be positive?


General tip: Consider to only ask 1 question per post.

Related : Deriving Lagrangian density for electromagnetic field.

Take L&L "derivations" from action principle with a truckload of salt. Their assumptions are hard to motivate, and you can change any of them and get some other mathematically plausible theory. The actual reason for the standard Lagrangian density function is that it produces the correct equations of motion, and is the simplest possible expression.
